# Duplicity does not work with lftp+ftps backend

Tags: ftps, lftp, duplicity

Trying to backup Ubuntu 18.04.1 server using `duplicity` to a FTPS (FTP over SSL) server.  The password is stored in the `FTP_PASSWORD` environment variable as suggested.  The duplicity command is:

```
duplicity /path/to/backup ftps://user@hostname/some/dir
```

The problem is that this translates into the following when it turns around and calls `lftp`

```
open -u 'user,pass` ftps://hostname
```

This will not work until you change the open command to (without the `ftps://` prefix on the hostname:

```
open -u 'user,pass` hostname
```

What I cannot figure out is either:

- How to tell `duplicity` not to build up the `open` command with the `ftps://` prefix.
- How to get `lftp` to work with the prefix

Note: The FTPS server works fine with other FTP clients, and even works properly with `lftp` as long as I build up the `open` command correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that lftp worked fine with ftps when I just wrote the hostname.
Duplicity whereas did fail with some TLS unexpected packet errors.

Solution was:
instead of writing ftps:// write ftpes://

```
duplicity /path/to/backup ftpes://user@hostname/some/dir
```

This changes how and when credentials will be encrypted by lftp.

Answer (score 0):

that seems wrong, https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html clearly states urls are viable

```
   open [OPTS] site

   Select  a  server  by host name, URL or bookmark. When an URL or bookmark
   is given, automaticallycally change the current working directory to the
   directory of the URL.  Options:

   ...
        --user user       use the user for authentication
        --password pass   use the password for authentication
        --env-password    take password from LFTP_PASSWORD environment variable
        site              host name, URL or bookmark name
```

also

```
   cmd:default-protocol (string)
          The value is used when `open' is used with just host name without
          protocol. Default is `ftp'.
```

so removing ftps:// simply makes lftp connect via ftp which is probably not what you want.

i'd suggest you to enable duplicity max. verbosity '-v9' and find out why lftp fails to connect via ftps://

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Thanks.  I can see exactly what duplicity is setting up, because it builds a temp file with all of the LFTP commands (passed using `-c` to lftp).  I'm going to have to experiment with some other FTPS servers besides the one that I was targeting.

Comment: After digging some more: `ftpsite.example.com` and `ftp://ftpsite.example.com` both cause `lftp` to connect over port 21.  Whereas `ftps://ftpsite.example.com` causes `lftp` to try and connect over port 990.  This particular server does not support port 990.

Comment: Worse, when you tell duplicity to attach to `ftp://somesite`, it puts `set ftp:ssl-allow false` into the command file being passed to `lftp` via the `-c` switch.  Which overrides a possible fix of putting `set ftp:ssl-allow true` in the `~/.lftprc` file.